# Cocoapods Quality Indexes : "tested" label not checked

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have an SDK published with cocoapods. 
Recently I made an update including a testing target.

Normally I should see the label tested checked but that doesn't happen. I double checked that the target is shared.

So my question here, Is there something special to add in Podspec ? Did they use some CI tools like TravisCI or jenkins to test the project.

I can't find something useful in the official documentation
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/quality-indexes.html
[image]

Comment: when you do pull requests into your GitHub repo, does it have any automated tests (e.g. Travis CI) running?

Comment: No, I have it in a seperated jenkins server. Could be that cocoapods check if the project is testeable against Travis CI on github ? I need to give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I found the answer in cocoapods source code :

Apperantly they are only checking the label if the pod has more than 5 tests which is not my case.

Check it here :

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods.org/blob/master/views/pod.slim#L9

```
  has_tests = @cocoadocs["total_test_expectations"] > 5
  tested_description = @cocoadocs["total_test_expectations"] > 20 ? "Tested" : "Well Tested"
```